# оптимальный код для нескольких owl carousel

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, в проекте используется плагин owl carousel.
Ситуация такова, что на некоторых страницах он должен выглядеть по разному в плане адаптивности. Но столкнулся с ситуацией, когда для каждой 'новой' карусели приходится заново ее инициализировать в результате чего появляется огромное количество повторяющегося кода...

```
var owl_index = $('#owl-index');
var owl_other = $('#owl-other');
var owl_other2 = $('#owl-other2');

owl_index.owlCarousel({
  loop              : false,
  margin            : 5,
  nav               : true,
  navText           : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
  responsiveClass   : true,
  responsive:{
    0:{  items      : 1
    },
    550:{ items     : 2
    },
    768:{ items     : 3
            },
    1200:{ items    : 4
    }
    }
    })

owl_other.owlCarousel({
  loop              : false,
  margin            : 6,
  nav               : true,
  navText           : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
  responsiveClass   : true,
  responsive:{
    0:{  items      : 1
    },
    550:{ items     : 2
    },
    992:{ items     : 3
            }
    }
    })
```

Боюсь представить, если будет подобных каруселей 10 а то и больше...
Прошу вашей помощи в оптимизации!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой способ, для каждой карусели пишите конфиг прямо в теге, например:

```
<div class='carousel' id='carousel2' data-params='{"loop":false,"margin":5}'></div>
```

Это работает если вы правильно сохраните данные в параметре. Затем их можно получить через jquery

```
$('carousel').each(function(){ 
  $(this).owlCarousel($(this).data('params'))
});
```

---

Второй способ. Создайте переменную

```
var owlParams = {loop:false,'margin':5, ... };
```

Затем для каждой карусели перед тем как инициализировать, изменяете в главной переменной те данные, которые отличаются:

```
owlParams.margin = 10;
$('.carousel').owlCarousel(owlParams);
```

Или можно совместить первое со вторым, в теге пишем только те данные, которые отличаются от переменной **owlParams**, затем следующее:

```
$('carousel').each(function(){ 
  $(this).owlCarousel($.extend({}, $(this).data('params'), owlParams))
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.